# RequireJS - get argument name

Tags: javascript, arguments, requirejs

I have an app using requirejs in a pretty simple method:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'scriptone',
    'scripttwo'
], function ($,scriptone,scripttwo) {

for(var i=0, max=arguments.length; i<max; i++){

    // What is the name of the argument ????

}

});
```

In the for loop I would like to be able to retrieve the name of the argument so as this loops through it would return '$', 'scriptone', 'scripttwo' ...

I know this is ultimately a question about functions and arguments, just wondering if in the context of RequireJS there is a simple/good method to achieve this?

Comment: there is a requirejs.arguments in the api , never tried it ,maybe interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never ever need to know variable names at runtime. There's something wrong with your application.

However, you can do it. Get a [serialisation of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString), remove comments etc, and parse the arguments list. To get the function itself, you might use deprecated [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) but better get a named reference to it. So you might end up with

```
var fn = arguments.callee.toString();
var args = fn
  .replace(/\/\/.*?\n|\/\*.*?\*\//g, "") // remove comments
  .match(/^function\s*\S*\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)/)[1] // match arguments list
  .split(/\s*,\s*/) // get argument names
for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
  console.log((args[i] || "unnamed argument")+":", arguments[i]);
```

Comment: I know it seems odd, but I'm using the names of the arguments to build a master object. I actually found a better way using an array and linking the array index with the argument index.